# Why I can't sign a Bitcoin transaction in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bitcoin

What is wrong with my code (I'm using [this gem](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby))?

```
require 'bitcoin'
include Bitcoin::Builder
key = Bitcoin::Key.from_base58('...')
txn = build_tx do |tx|
  tx.input do |i|
    i.prev_out(Bitcoin::P::Tx.from_hash(...))
    i.prev_out_index(0)
    i.signature_key(Bitcoin::Key.from_base58(...))
  end
  tx.output do |o|
    o.value(50000)
    o.to('1GzqkR2zNQUzHLpE7PLPjVNJ51FHC3bpDH')
  end
end
```

I'm getting:

```
RuntimeError: Script type must be hash160, pubkey, p2wpkh or multisig
    /Users/yegor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bitcoin-ruby-0.0.19/lib/bitcoin/builder.rb:239:in `sig_hash_and_all_keys_exist?'
    /Users/yegor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bitcoin-ruby-0.0.19/lib/bitcoin/builder.rb:308:in `sign_input'
    /Users/yegor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bitcoin-ruby-0.0.19/lib/bitcoin/builder.rb:208:in `block in tx'
    /Users/yegor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bitcoin-ruby-0.0.19/lib/bitcoin/builder.rb:207:in `each'
    /Users/yegor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bitcoin-ruby-0.0.19/lib/bitcoin/builder.rb:207:in `each_with_index'
    /Users/yegor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bitcoin-ruby-0.0.19/lib/bitcoin/builder.rb:207:in `tx'
    /Users/yegor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bitcoin-ruby-0.0.19/lib/bitcoin/builder.rb:21:in `build_tx'
```

What am I doing wrong? BTW, no matter what private key I provide to the `signature_key` I get the same error. If I remove the line with `singature_key`, I get no error.

I submitted a ticket to their repo too: https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby/issues/287

Comment: The output from your exception seems to be missing something. Did you omit some lines? In particular, I don't see any line corresponding to your own code.

Comment: @MichaelHampton me neither, and this is the problem...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was with the format of the script. This code works:

```
utxo = # coming from https://www.blockchain.info/api/unspent
  builder.input do |i|
    i.prev_out(utxo['tx_hash_big_endian'])
    i.prev_out_index(utxo['tx_output_n'])
    i.prev_out_script = [utxo['script']].pack('H*')
    i.signature_key(key)
  end
```